# Регулярное выражение для удаления определённого атрибута HTML

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как удалить из строки с html кодом, в тэгах `img` все атрибуты `data-index=""`?

К примеру

```
$html = '<img src="#" data-index="1" />
<img src="#" data-index="2" />
<img src="#" data-index="2" />';
```

Должен превратиться в

```
$html = '<img src="#"/>
<img src="#"/>
<img src="#"/>';
```

Подскажите регулярку

Comment: `$string = '<img src="#" data-index="1" />
<img src="#" data-index="2" />
<img src="#" data-index="2" />';
$pattern = '/data-index="\w+"/i';
$replacement = '$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот это:

```
$reg = '/data-index=".+"/';
preg_replace($reg, "", $html)
```